# Unit Step Function

Tags: plotting, functions

I will like to plot the unit step function of common function 
, For example  f(t)=H(t-4)t or f(t)=H(t-4)t^2
I have search through the Help Menu but cant really get a lead to the plotting. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> search through the Help Menu but cant really get a lead to the
>   plotting

It is really no different than other type of Plot?

```
Plot[UnitStep[t - 4]*t, {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, if you want the engineer plot, you can do

```
Plot[UnitStep[t - 4]*t, {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similarly,

```
 Plot[UnitStep[t - 4]*t^2, {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image]

Comment: Plot[UnitStep[t - 4], {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}] and Plot[UnitStep[6*(t - 4], {t, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}] returned the same graph

Comment: @MKA `returned the same graph` that is correct. It should be the same graph.  btw, you have syntax error in your second plot. I corrected it.  All what `UnitStep` does, is it looks at its argument. If the argument is less than zero, it returns `0`, else it returns `1`. In your second plot, the argument is `6*t-24`. So when `t>=4` it changes from `0` to `1` which is the same thing as if you wrote `UnitStep[t-4]` which returns `0` when `t<4` and returns `1` when `t>=4`